# Two non-isomorphic ways to present a finite p-group as a semidirect product

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

I'm looking for a finite p-group $G$ that can be presented in two non isomorphic ways as semidirect product $N\rtimes C_{p}$ where $C_{p}$ is the cyclic group with p elements. Two smidirect products are isomorphic if there is an automorphism $G\to G$ that commutes with the embeddings of $C_{p}$  and an isomorphism $N_{1}\to N_2$ and s.t. the exact sequences $$\begin{matrix}1 & \to & N_{1} & \to & G & \to & C_{p} & \to & 1\\
 &  & \downarrow &  & \downarrow &  & \downarrow\\
1 & \to & N_{2} & \to & G & \to & C_{p} & \to & 1
\end{matrix}$$ commute.

Comment: actually I want the automorphism of G to commute with the embeddings of Cp as well

Comment: Try the dihedral group of order $8$. You can do this in two ways with non-isomorphic groups $N$.

Comment: Is the map $C_p\ \longrightarrow\ C_p$ required to be the identity?

Comment: I was thiniking of something of the sort of S7 that can be asemidirect product of C2 and A7 in two non-isomorphic ways. because there isn't any automorphism of S7 sending  (1 2)  to (1 2)(3 4)(5 6).

Comment: @NoamKolodner $S_n$ is not a $p$-group.

Comment: yeah i'm looking for a similar example with a p-group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $G=D_4$ the dihedral group of order $8$ (so it's a $2$-group). If you write

$$D_4=<r, s\ |\ r^4=s^2=(sr)^2=1>$$

then put

$$N_1=<r>$$
$$N_2=<s, rsr^{-1}>$$

Note that obviously $N_1\simeq\mathbb{Z}_4$ while $N_2\simeq\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$. Since both are of order $4$ then they are of index $2$ hence they are normal and

$$G/N_1\simeq G/N_2\simeq \mathbb{Z}_2$$

But $N_1\not\simeq N_2$.